# How to avoid methods with different parameters

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

I have many similar methods with different parameters. I tried to find a good and simple refactoring solution but with no result. I can use a parameter object but I think then I need to create another helper class, and it will make everything more complex and slower.

```
void Foo(ref int test2)
{
    Goo(test2);
}

void Foo(ref long test2)
{
    Goo(test2);
}

void Foo(ref double test2)
{
    Goo(test2);
}

void Foo(ref string test2)
{
    if (!test2.IsNull())
        test2 = "sth";
    Goo(test2);
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for *generics*? `void Foo<T>(ref T test2)`

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a more complex example. We have no idea what `Goo` does, or why your first three methods are accepting `ref` parameters despite not changing them.

Answer (score 3):

Use [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
void Foo<T>(ref T test2)
{
    Goo(test2);
}
```

Comment: This only works if `Goo` is a generic method and not a family of overloads in the same was `Foo` is.

Comment: How does this help in the last scenario where there is type specific (i.e. `!test2.IsNull()`) processing going on?

Answer (score 2):

1. Multiple method overload is not that bad thing that have to be avoided or refactored. So think twice before refactor it.
2. Your methods seems to be equal, but they don't are. Please have a look at implementation of Foo method for string parameter. There is an input value replacement in case of null. In case of ***generic*** implemetation the case should be still covered over the type checking
3. From your example I see that you have a nested methods call, but re-implemented accordantelly input argument type. Please find it out maybe it was done by purpose? It could be that your code is a part of API to be referenced in other languages that do not have a notion of ***generics***.

If you still sure that you have to refactor it then the following options are possible:

- Generic
- OOP (polimorfism and virtualization)
- Use Dynamic or object Type of input argument (be really carefull about boxing and type comparison)
- If you want to reduce amout of code you have to mantain, but the final code with a lot of implementations of the same method is ok for you, in that case T4 can be an option

Comment: Yea, I think that you're right. In real there are a lot of code's line, but all in all it's not so bad. Generic are not good in my case beacause of others actions in those functions. I thought about object types, but this is dangerous, and can be worst than is. OOP can be an answer, but I have to think more about this case. I will post answer after a weekend, maybe I will find good solution.